# Does placement of the style (CSS) element matter in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Does placement of:

```
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>
```

matter? Is there any difference if I place it inside page div, or inside body? I recently found out it matters with javascript. I had some problems with my CSS also (jQuery Mobile). Could it be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style element should apply to the whole document, wherever it is placed, however it is common practice to always put it in the head element. I would not be surprised if browser handling is a bit flaky if you put it in other places.

Note that html5 allows you to specify the scoped attribute for the style element, which means that it will only apply to the parent element of the style element and all its children.

By the way, usual practice is to put the css in a separate file and use the `<link>` tag to include the CSS in your document. This way you can share the css across multiple pages.

Comment: I would like to point out that sometimes you add css styles after pageload (so with javascript or ajax). You cannot add it to the head section, so it would be placed between the body tags. But as pointed out, this should not be a problem. CSS errors will never break your page, they can mess up your layout though.

Answer (score 1):

The placement matters as regards to order of style sheets. When resolving conflicts between style sheets, then at the last step, when other things are equal, the rule that comes last wins. Thus, it matters how the `style` element is placed relative to other style element and to `link` elements that refer to style sheets. (It does not matter as regards to `style` attributes in elements, since other things can’t be equal: the attributes win, by specificity.)

It also matters in validation: a `style` element is not valid except within a `head` element. Browsers don’t care about this, though.

JavaScript code can of course be dependent on the placement of the elements it processes. It’s all up to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should not, but don't do it, it is just bad practice, plus makes your code looks messy

Comment: Could you specify? I usually do put css between </head> and <body> is that correct?

Comment: try maintaining a separate CSS file and include that in between <head></head>
it should look something like
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: corrected downvote with an upvote, this is not an incorrect or incomplete answer, just not that elaborate

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question directly, usually if you're placing your code straight in the page, you'll be placing it in the `<head>` of the page. Should work regardless of where you put it, but `<head>` is common practice. Not sure what exactly your goal is, but for email, I typically split it up into inline styling (placing relevant code in the HTML tags themselves, like `<p style="line-height:1.4em;">`).

If you're working on webpages, though, unless there's a particular reason to have the CSS embedded in the code of the page itself, it's almost always better (and it considered best practice) to link to an external stylesheet in between your `<head>` tags (`<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="[YOUR STYLESHEET]" type="text/css"> </head>`). It keeps your HTML cleaner, and helps with the separation of markup (HTML), styling (CSS), and functionality (JavaScript).

Hope that answers your question somewhat, haha.